# Different arrangements - Permutation

Tags: permutations

Into how many different arrangements that look different can three identical trigonometry books, 4 identical calculus books, 5 identical algebra books be placed on a shelf?

Comment: I assume the word "books" are meant to be placed after each branch of mathematics?

Comment: @user92774 Oh yes! Those are books. Sorry for that.

Comment: We are looking at the $12$-letter words made up of the letters t,t,t,c,c,c,c,a,a,a,a,a.

Answer (score 1):

Start by simply counting how many ways there are to shelve the 12 books. Then modify the number you get to account for fact that you could swap around, say, the trigonometry books with one another and still get the same arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

(3+4+5)!/(3!4!5!) = 12!/(3!4!5!) = 27,720 ways.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at the $12$-letter words made up of the letters t,t,t,c,c,c,c,a,a,a,a,a.

We have $12$ "slots." The slots for the t's can be chosen in $\binom{12}{3}$ ways. For each choice, the slots for the c's can be chosen in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways. And once we have done this, there is only $1$ way to place the a's (or if you prefer there are $\binom{5}{5}$ ways).